# dotnet core IdentityModel will not introspect tokens

Tags: c#, .net-core, thinktecture-ident-model

I'm playing around with porting one of my API applications to dotnet core (v2), and probably the most important part of that upgrade is getting my Authentication working.

To that end, I've added Thinkteture's IdentityModel package to my project.

How my API works is it receives an Authentication header in the form of a bearer token from the caller.  I then `Introspect` that token to verify it is acceptable for the current task, and proceed with the main logic.

However, I seem  to simply be missing something absolutely basic  in the initial set up of the  code, for I am unable to get the introspection to fire at all.

Following, I have  some snippets from my `Startup.cs`, and a controller.

**Startup.cs**

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthentication(OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOAuth2Introspection(options =>
            {
                options.IntrospectionEndpoint = "#REDACTED#";

                options.ClientId = "#REDACTED#";
                options.ClientSecret = "#REDACTED#";

            });
        var x = 1;

    }
```

**ItemsController.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
       return new string[] { "isAuthenticated", $"{User.Identity.IsAuthenticated}" };
    }
```

This endpoint (GET api/items) always returns false, and my OIDC server app never logs any attempts to communicate with it.  A breakpoint set on the `services.AddAuthentication()` code catches, so I know that the basic setup pieces are in place.

Some other things I've tried:

- putting an `Authorize` decoration on the method (didn't really expect this to work.. and it didn't)
- Using `Authority` options, and allowing discovery of the introspection endpoint (I'd thought perhaps that my OIDC server maybe didn't support discovery, and that was causing the problems, but supplying the introspection endpoint doesn't make any difference)

I'm sure I've missed something completely trivial, but after spending a few hours poking, searching, and trying assorted things, I've realized that I must just be overlooking it.

Answer (score 3):

Even if this answer comes late i would like to ask if you have tried setting `SkipTokensWithDots` to `false`.

what worked for me was:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOAuth2Introspection(options =>
    {
        options.IntrospectionEndpoint = "#REDACTED#";

        options.ClientId = "#REDACTED#";
        options.ClientSecret = "#REDACTED#";

        // We are using introspection for JWTs so we need to override the default
        options.SkipTokensWithDots = false;
    });
```

Comment: Has anyone been able to get this working? I am running into the same problem. Tokens are being issued from a third-party IDaaS service. Our IntrospectionEndpoint address is correct, as is the Client ID and Client Secret (and the token we're passing). Having a hard time trying to figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: You can also configure a TokenRetrieval func to get the reference token string

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the [Authorize] attribute in the controller. THis is why the middleware is not even trying to introspect the token and thus you don't get any trace info .